# How to use JPA CriteriaBuilder with substring in where clause?

Tags: jpa, substring

I want a SQL where clause like below:

```
where t.xcode = substring(xxx, 1, length(t.xcode))
```

How can I do this by JPA CriteriaBuilder?

I tried

```
cb.equal(path.get('xcode').as(String.class), xxx.substing(1, ???))
```

But I don't know how to define the ??? part.

Comment: Or any one knows other method to do this query?

Comment: Available JPQL functions are shown in this link http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql.html#functions  and there is clearly a LENGTH(...) so there is consequently a length method on CriteriaBuilder. When you try that what happens?